# Update the Queryset of a Django-Select2 AutoModelSelect2Field

Tags: python, django, jquery-select2

I can't figure out how to update the queryset of a AutoModelSelect2Field dynamically. I'm getting really strange results. For example, sometimes the select2 box will return the correct, filtered results, and sometimes it will return NO results when I enter the same characters.

my code:

```
#views.py
form = MyForm()


#forms.py
class MyField(AutoModelSelect2Field):
    search_fields = ['name__icontains']
    max_results = 10


class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = MyField(
        queryset=project.objects.none(),
        required=True,
        widget=AutoHeavySelect2Widget(
            select2_options={
                'width': '100%',
            }
        )
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = kwargs.pop('queryset')
        self.base_fields['my_field'].queryset = qs
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.fields['my_field'].queryset = qs
        #self.base_fields['my_field'].queryset = qs
```

A few of the things I've tried -

update from the view:

```
#views.py
form = MyForm()
form.base_fields['my_field'].queryset = new_qs
```

and:

```
form = MyForm()
form.fields['my_field'].queryset = new_qs
```

pass the qs to the form:

```
#views.py
form = MyForm(queryset=Project.objects.filter(project_type=pt))

# see above code for forms.py
```

I've also tried setting the initial qs to all objects:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = MyField(
        queryset=project.objects,
        ...
```

But I get the same problem, 90% of the time I get the results of the initial queryset, rather than the filtered objects based on the new qs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were able to find a pretty straightforward way to get the dropdown options to filter by additional fields (ie. first select country and then have the state dropdown only showing states from the selected country)

It was inspired by a suggestion from here (where we also posted this solution):
https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2/issues/22

in forms.py:

```
class StateChoices(AutoModelSelect2Field):
    queryset = State.objects
    def get_results(self, request, term, page, context):
        country =  request.GET.get('country', '')

        states = State.objects.filter(country=country, name__istartswith=term)
        s2_results = [(s.id, s.name, {}) for s in states]

        return ('nil', False, s2_results)
```

the form field:

```
# only include this when you would have a screen where the country 
# is preset and would not change, but you want to use it as a search context
country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all(),
                                 widget=forms.HiddenInput())
state = StateChoices(widget = AutoHeavySelect2Widget(
    select2_options = {
        'minimumInputLength': 1,
        'ajax': {
            'dataType': 'json',
            'quietMillis': 100,
            'data': JSFunctionInContext('s2_state_param_gen'),
            'results': JSFunctionInContext('django_select2.process_results'),
        }
    }))
```

in our javascript:

```
function s2_state_param_gen(term, page) {
    var proxFunc = $.proxy(django_select2.get_url_params, this);
    results = proxFunc(term, page, 's2_condition_param_gen');
    results.country = $('#id_country').val();
    return results;
}
```